# problem with python: undefined symbol: sqmI

Tags: python, mdanalysis

i have installed on my Ubuntu, this package: pyinteraph.py
after the installation, i have this problem:

```
File "/home/user/Scrivania/PyInteraph-1.0/test/pyinteraph/pyinteraph", line 162, in <module>
 from libinteract import libinteract as li
  File "/home/user/Scrivania/PyInteraph-1.0/test/lib/python/libinteract/libinteract.py", line 8, in <module>
    from innerloops import LoopDistances
ImportError: /home/user/Scrivania/PyInteraph-1.0/test/lib/python/libinteract/innerloops.so: undefined symbol: sqmI
```

I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: how did you install this package?

Comment: I followed the instructions, written in the INSTALL file:
python setup.py install

Comment: It looks like you need to install some other dependencies too. Did you follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/ELELAB/pyinteraph/blob/master/INSTALL)?

Comment: yes they are. But i have a problem with the  Install of the prerequisites. 
When i do this command:        sudo apt-get install python-dev python-cython python-numpy g++ gcc
appear:
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto python-cython
(python-cython not found)

Comment: maybe try without the `python-cython` package?

Comment: ok... but appear that i have installed both g++ and gcc :(

Comment: the error remains

Comment: what version is your `MDAnalysis`? the installation instructions specify to use version < 0.8. Can you verify that this is the case for you?

Comment: now, i have uninstalled MDAnalysis and re-install MDAnalysis=0.7.6 (how write in the istruction) but i have an error:
   from MDAnalysis.analysis.distances import distance_array
  File "/home/z4-19/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDAnalysis/analysis/distances.py", line 31, in <module>
    from scipy import weave
ImportError: cannot import name weave

Comment: see my answer below: it's a little hacky, but you'll have to edit a couple lines in the MDAnalysis file here: `/home/z4-19/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDAnalysis/analysis/distances.py`. see step 10 and replace the path with the path of the file in your error message. You will also need to `pip install weave`

Comment: yes, work. but i have the same problem, after run tutorial.sh

Comment: same problem? `cannot ipmort name weave`?

Comment: no this one: 
File "/home/user/Scrivania/PyInteraph-1.0/test/pyinteraph/pyinteraph", line 162, in <module>
 from libinteract import libinteract as li
  File "/home/user/Scrivania/PyInteraph-1.0/test/lib/python/libinteract/libinteract.py", line 8, in <module>
    from innerloops import LoopDistances
ImportError: /home/user/Scrivania/PyInteraph-1.0/test/lib/python/libinteract/innerloops.so: undefined symbol: sqmI

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install and get it working on my machine with a few tweaks... It's definitely not ideal, hopefully the package maintainers can update the installation instructions.

Here's what I did:

1. make a new directory for your project, `mkdir myproj`
2. change directories into your new directory `cd myproj`
3. create new virutalenv `virtualenv --python=python2.7 venv`
4. activate virutalenv `source venv/bin/activate`
5. `pip install numpy scipy matplotlib networkx weave`
6. `pip install MDAnalysis==0.7.6`
7. Clone the pyinteraph repo: `git clone https://github.com/ELELAB/pyinteraph.git`
8. cd pyinteraph
9. python setup.py install
10. (this is where it gets a little hacky...) because of this [issue](https://github.com/ELELAB/pyinteraph/issues/5) here with scipy, we need to edit the MDAnalysis file to import `weave` instead of `scipy.weave`. Change a couple lines in the file `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MDAnalysis/analysis/distances.py` from:

```py
import numpy
from scipy import sparse
from scipy import weave
from scipy.weave import converters
```

to

```py
import numpy
from scipy import sparse
#  from scipy import weave
#  from scipy.weave import converters

import weave
from weave import converters
```

Then to check if it is working, open up a python shell and try:

```py
from libinteract import libinteract
```

If there are no errors, you are good to go.

**EDIT:** the maintainers have a py3 version available [here](https://github.com/ELELAB/pyinteraph2)

Comment: could you try if you are able to run tutorial.sh in examples?

Comment: when i check from libinteract import libinteract
i have this error :( :( 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/z4-19/Scrivania/pietro/pyinteraph-master/examples/myproj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libinteract/libinteract.py", line 8, in <module>
    from innerloops import LoopDistances
ImportError: /home/z4-19/Scrivania/pietro/pyinteraph-master/examples/myproj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libinteract/innerloops.so: undefined symbol: sqmI

Comment: i believe this `sqml` error is related to the version of MDAnalysis. Can you `pip list` and verify the version is correct? when you are running python, are you using the correct python interpreter?

Comment: MDAnalysis (0.7.6)

Comment: this is inside the virtualenv, correct? i believe you were on the right track when you were receiving the `weave` error. is it possible for you to recreate that?

Comment: Do you really need MDAnalysis 0.7.6 – this is a terribly outdated version; the current one (January 2020) is 0.20.1. Modern versions of Python [install easily with conda or pip](https://www.mdanalysis.org/pages/installation_quick_start/). EDIT: According to issue [ELELAB/pyinteraph #4](https://github.com/ELELAB/pyinteraph/issues/4#issuecomment-576600909) it does need MDAnalysis 0.7.6 and they are working on upgrading. I would say your best shot is a virtual environment full of old versions of Python, numpy, scipy, MDAnalysis.